# Execute command on every fourth line in text file using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute a grep command on lines 2,6,10,14... of a file but this doesn't quite work. It seems I have an error with the if statement. Any ideas?

```
count=0

while read p; do
    if [$count%4==2]
    then
        grep $p /dir/file.txt | wc -l >> output.txt
        (( count++ ))
    fi  
done < /dir/file.txt
```

In the end I would like this script to list in output.txt how many times line 2 is repeated in the file, then how many times line 6 is repeated, and 10, and 14 etc.

Comment: Instead of `if [$count%4==2]` use `if (( count%4 == 2))`

Comment: You should add one to count after fi, and before done.  Otherwise count only gets 1 added when $count%4 == 2.  Count should go up for every line in the file, not just when %4 == 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell syntax is hosed; you need whitespace inside the square brackets; but the modulo operator is not a feature of the `[` built-in so you need to make several unattractive changes to fix it.

Anyway, this can be enormously simplified using Awk.

```
awk -v pat="$p" '(NR % 4) == 2 && $0 ~ pat { ++count }
    END { print count }' /dir/file.txt
```

`NR` is the current line number and `$0` is the current input line.  `pat` is the pattern which you pass in as a variable from the shell variable `$p`.

Comment: so I think this looks good, but I made one modification by adding 'output.txt' at the end of the last line, an the script outputs a single count and then seems to run forever without ending.

Comment: If you want to redirect to `output.txt` you need to add `>output.txt` not just the file name.

Comment: sorry i mistyped that. I did add that. I actually have >>output.txt at the end.

Comment: I assumed you actually want an aggregate count.  If you want to output a literal `1` for each matching line then `print "1"` instead of `++count` and lose the entire `END` block.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a tool for awk, you have access to a variable NR which is the number of the row it is currently processing, so for example, `seq 14` outputs the numbers from 1 to 14, one per line:

```
$ seq 14 | awk '(NR+2) % 4==0'
2
6
10
14
```

Comment: ... and add `| grep "$p"` to extract only those lines which match; use `grep -c` to get a count (piping to `wc -l` in an antipattern).

Answer (score 1):

Sed has line-skipping. Use that to get only the lines you want to test, and then grep the result.

```
$ sed -e "2,~4p" -e d <infile |grep $p
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all grep works on file. If you want to grep for a pattern in particular lines, then you can do this :

```
i=1; 
while read -r line;  
do 
   if [ $((i++ % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "$line" | grep $p >> output.txt
   fi
done </dir/file.txt
```